# image based buttons are blurred in IE9

Tags: css, button, internet-explorer-9

I have created css3 buttons based on bootstrap 3.1.1. These css3 buttons fall back to image based buttons in case of IE8 and IE9. You can check the demo here at
http://unirazz.com/css3-btns/index.html

The problem is the smaller buttons (with class .btn-success) are blurred in IE9 only, in all other browser they are working fine. I found that if I changed the display to block (from inline-block) then the image is optimized otherwise blurred. How to fix it without changing the display: inline-block

here is my css code

```
a.btn-primary, a.btn-success {
    display: inline-block; /* change to block then it is not blurred */
    height: 27px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-indent: -999em;
    border: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the fix. I need to set the border-radius: 0px

```
.btn-primary, btn-success {
    border-radius: 0px;
}
```